# RegEx Overlapping String

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this.

`[system]a[/system][system]b[/system][system]c[/system]`

I want to return values between [system] and [/system] tags.

So for this example it should return a, b, c. (with preg_match_all function in php)

I tried to use this pattern `\[system\](.*)\[\/system\]` but it returns `a[/system][system]b[/system][system]c`.

It simply takes the first opening tag and finishes with last closing tag.

How can i do this?

Comment: Add a `?` i.e change `(.*)` to non-greedy `(.*?)`

Comment: @degant Thanks, it worked. You should post this in answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your quantifier non-greedy (reluctant). Add a `?` like this:

```
(.*?)
```

This will instruct the regex to match **as few as possible** instead of being greedy and matching as many as possible.